# When applying the Canny function, can you apply the mask first?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been learning about the Canny Edge Detection function, the Hough Transform and masking to select a particular set of edges in an image.

I was just wondering - I've seen people apply those two functions first and the mask second. Would applying the mask first improve performance?

Surely if you only apply the Canny function and Hough transform on the masked region that would be faster than applying them to the entire region and then picking the masked region. But perhaps I am misunderstanding.

I am not sure if it's relevant, but I am using Python and the OpenCV library. I am aware that its functions cannot operate on a subset of the image. But I'd like to understand why that is the case.

Comment: hiw would you apply the mask first?  If you make all not masked pixel black in the canny input you'll get most likely many edges at the masked border. Might or might not be what you desire...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can apply the mask first, but this will give seriously sub-par results.

For example, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from skimage import feature

# Create image
image = scipy.misc.face(gray=True)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('image')

# Create a simple mask
x, y = np.mgrid[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1]]
mask = (x > 200) & (x < 500) & (y > 300) & (y < 700)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image * mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('masked image')

# Find edges with both methods
edges1 = feature.canny(image, sigma=3)
edges1 *= mask

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(edges1, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Mask then find edges')

masked_image = image * mask
edges2 = feature.canny(masked_image, sigma=3)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(edges2, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Find edges then mask')
```

Which gives these results:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice how, if you mask before you apply the edge detector, you get this weird frame. This is because masking creates new edges that were not there from the start.

Comment: I see - so if you were to try filling it in, you'd get a red box basically due to this 'frame'?

Comment: Yes, that is what you would get. With that said, if your mask is rectangular, you could extract that subset of the image and apply the edge detector to it separately.

Comment: you should add some boundary region around the mask equal to the gradient filter size used in/before canny if you want identical results to the full-image-size result.